# Conversion from derived class to it's base class is widening? Why?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

According to page

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e.aspx

conversion from derived class to it's base class is widening. I thought that this is opposite: it's narrowing conversion. because base class object is a part of derived class's object.

How to explain this in detail that this is widening conversion?

Comment: Because it has a wider range of compatible types then.

Comment: A derived class usually has a more specific (ie narrow) role.  Conversely, a base class has a broader scope, so it's widening.

Comment: The base class is more Abstract versus the derived class is more specific.

Comment: Btw, java has the same rules: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html _"A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type S to any reference type T, provided S is a subtype (§4.10) of T."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page you linked:

> It might seem surprising that a conversion from a derived type to one of its base types is widening. The justification is that the derived type contains all the members of the base type, so it qualifies as an instance of the base type. In the opposite direction, the base type does not contain any new members defined by the derived type.

Comment: I don't like the explanation from MSDN much. Why is it wider when it contains all members of the base type? It's remains suprising after reading that. If you cosider _wider_ a synonym of _general_ and _narrow_ of _specific_ it is clearer. A base type is a more gereneral tape and the derived types are more specific.